# Updating JSON Array records using only UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a TableView that contains rows populated from JSON.

The JSON is generated by a PHP script populated from mySQL database

I would like to select multiple records from this TableView all together take and update the SQL record.

Can someone steer me towards how this can be done?

Should an HTTP Post Request be used for this?

I am currently selecting records by:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        //tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
        {
            print(String(indexPath.row))
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark
            {

                print("DESELECT POSITION = \(indexPath)")
                index = Int(indexPath.row)
                if let index = saveCheckmarkArray.index(of: index!)
                {
                    saveCheckmarkArray.remove(at: index)
                }
                print("Final Array \(saveCheckmarkArray)")
                cell.accessoryType = .none

            }
            else
            {
                print("SELECT POSITION = \(indexPath)")
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                index = Int(indexPath.row)
                saveCheckmarkArray.append(index!)

            }
        }

    }
```

you can seprate this code in select and deselect delegate methods.whichever works for you.
Hope you get the logic behind how you can achieve this.

Comment: This is very interesting, but not exactly what I was looking for, can you please see my other post? It is similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/57405620/11890142

Comment: I have checked the question and it depends upon how the API POST parameters are passed either you can call the API whenever the user click on YES / NO toggle or else as we have saved the array of selected index position add and DONE button on your screen and when Done button is pressed call the API where you know which index position should be YES and NO .