# Modifying a JSON array in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can't seem to understand how a JSON array be edited when presented in a UITableView?

```
The JSON array looks like the following example:

[
    {
        "customer": "John",
        "status": "Yes",
    },
    {
        "customer": "James",
        "status": "No",
    },
    {
        "customer": "Jamie",
        "status": "No",
    }
]
```

**The way the app currently presents the data in the UITableView:**

```
private func fetchJSON() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example/example/example"),
        let value = driver.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "driver=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([Structure].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()

}
```

**TableView Delegate code so far:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering() {
        return pickup.count
    }
    print(structure.count)
    return structure.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testingCell", for: indexPath)


    let portfolio: Structure

    portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none

}
```

I would like to be able to select the customers names James and Jamie and press a button that will change the status from No to Yes.

**How can the selection and update mechanism be created from the apps perspective?**

**UPDATE:**

structure is defined as: `var structure = [Structure]()`

```
import UIKit

struct Structure: Codable {
    let customer: String
    let status: String
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I am working with the following but I cannot seem to update the API:

```
func saveToDB(_ structure: Structure) {
    do{
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(structure)
        if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(str)

                guard let url = URL(string: "https://example/example/example"),
        else { return }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: add your tableview delegate method codes.

Comment: @VinuJacob Ok I have added some more details

Comment: Do you want to change the value in the array?

Comment: @MalsLanster you want multiple selection for the tableview Right?

Comment: You want to change status in model class or in ViewController's Array only ???

Answer (score 0):

You must change the `status` in `structure` `array` w.r.t the *selected* `indexPath` and not in the *JSON* directly.

In `tableView(_: didSelectRowAt:)` and `tableView(_: didDeselectRowAt:)`, you can simply change the `status` value of `structure` at that particular `indexPath` like so,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    structure[indexPath.row].status = "Yes"
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    structure[indexPath.row].status = "No"
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

In case the issue is not resolved, do add the definition of `Structure` along with more details, so I can help you further.

**Edit:**

First of all, the definition of `Structure` goes like,

```
class Structure: Codable {
    var customer: String
    var status: String
}
```

The code to update the `status` of `structure` an `indexPath` is:

```
class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var structures = [Structure]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        fetchJSON()
    }

    private func fetchJSON() {
        //code to fetch data from JSON...
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return structures.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testingCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = structures[indexPath.row].customer
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let structure = structures[indexPath.row]
        structure.status = "Yes"
        saveToDB(structure)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let structure = structures[indexPath.row]
        structure.status = "No"
        saveToDB(structure)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }

    func saveToDB(_ structure: Structure) {
        //add the code to save structure in DB...
    }
}
```

Now, when saving to the *DB*, there is no need for the *JSON response*. You can directly save the `structure` instance in the *DB*.

**Edit-2:**

Update the `saveToDB(_:)` method to:

```
func saveToDB(_ structure: Structure) {
    do{
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(structure)
        if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(str)
            //str is the updated Structure that you can send in your API...
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In the above method, you'll get the *JSON format* of the updated `structure` instance that you can use to call your API.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will resolve your problem

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testingCell", for: indexPath)

        let portfolio: Structure = structure[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = portfolio.status == "YES" ? .checkmark : .none

        return cell

    }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let status = structure[indexPath.row].status // get current status
    structure[indexPath.row].status = status == "YES" ? "NO" : "YES" /// toggle status
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

No need `didDeselectRowAt` method.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I keep getting the error, Expected expression after '?' in ternary expression in the line: `structure[indexPath.row].status = status == "YES" ? : "NO" : "YES" /// toggle status`

Comment: Sorry there were some syntactical error. Correct my answer, check it.